# UITableViewCell with a horizontal UITableView

Tags: ios5, uitableview, horizontal-scrolling

I want to implement a vertical UITableView whose cells contain horizontally scrolling table views. It should behave pretty much like the table view in the Pulse app. That, as mentioned by the developers in their Stanford presentation, contains horizontal table views in each cell.

I've read Ray Wenderlich's blog post, but he mentioned that in iOS 5 it can be done a lot easier than his tutorial and that the procedure would be described when iOS 5 is released (which it has been for almost a year and no blog post about the matter has been posted).

Could someone please give me a hint how to go about it? I am adding a tableview to my cells and I'm rotating it by -M_PI_2. The width of the cells is set to be the height of the cells in the main table. The height of the horizontal table is set to be 320. However, it doesn't scroll when I start moving my finger on it and I don't really know why.

Sorin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer (the Ray Wenderlich tutorial on the matter)

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2